# How can I detect negative Hex Values in C#?

Tags: c#, hex

I am working on a driver for a temperature sensor.
The values are coming in Hex form and they are stored like:

```
string tempHex = "08C5"; //-> Would be 22,45°C
```

The problem is, the sensor can also notice negative values and I have no idea how I can detect the 2's complement in C#.

Maybe you can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the datasheet of the sensor? Usualy in the datasheet you get a **math expression** to convert *raw data* in *utile data*.

Comment: I did, but the problem is, they only say that negative values are shown in 2's complement form.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "the values are coming in hex form"? You're actually reading them as *strings*? That seems very odd. Is it always 2 bytes? This question is too vague at the moment... if you could show what you've got so far, that would really help.

Comment: If the values are in 2's complement form, could you not get the binary/raw data and check the first few bits?

Comment: Yes, i actually get them as string. Is that a problem?

Comment: it's not a problem but it's inefficient

Comment: Many low level interfaces to embedded systems actually transmit data as ASCII hex strings, not binary. This is because they want to be "human accessible" so that you can use Hyperterm (gag) to access the data, but the firmware doesn't have a full `printf` stack. I've seen this problem several times and it has been done this way for decades.

Answer (score 19):

```
static public double Temp(string hex)
{
    return Convert.ToInt16(hex,16)*0.01;
}
```

Values from 0000 to 7FFF will be positive, 8000 to FFFF will be negative. Luckily, `Convert.ToInt16()` does this all for you, as this is exactly how the numbers are stored internally on all modern computers. You just have to multiple by 0.01 to get Celsius.

Answer (score 5):

A simple [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx) would do, it's as complicated as implementing the 2's complement imho.
For example:

```
static bool isPositive(string hex)
{
    return Convert.ToInt16(hex, 16)>0;
}
```

Comment: This will not work for the example data. For a 4 digit hex string (as shown in the example), all values will be positive, as `Convert.ToInt32("FFFF",16)` will be 65535 not -1. To get a negative `Int32` you need a 8 digit hex string that starts with 8 to F. Use `Convert.ToInt16` instead.